# Injective function and Identity function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

let $A$ be a finite set.

Also let $f : A \to A$ be an injective function. prove that there is $m\in \mathbb{N}$ so $f^m=Id_{A}$.

If we assume that there is no $m\in \mathbb{N}$ so $f^m=id_A$ then there exsits $a\in A$ so $f^m\neq x$ therefore $f(f^{m-1}(a))\neq x$ but what now?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is finite and $f$ is injective, then $f$ is actually a bijection. Therefore, $f$ is a permutation of the elements of $A$ and so $f^{(\#A)!}=\operatorname{Id}_A$, since the order of the group of the permutations of $A$ is $(\#A)!$.

You can also prove it as follows: since $f$ is a permutation of the elements of $A$, $f$ can be expressed as a composition of disjoint cycles. If $f$ is a single cycle, then $f^l=\operatorname{Id}_A$, where $l$ is the length of the cycle. In the general case, let $l$ be the least common multiple (or, for that matter, *any* common multiple) of the lengths of the cycles, and then $f^l=\operatorname{Id}_A$.

This can also be proved using the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) and without making any mention to groups or permutations. Let us suppose that the statement is false. Then there is a finite set $A$ and an injective function $f\colon A\longrightarrow A$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):f^n\neq\operatorname{Id}_A$ and that $A$ has the minimal size among all conterexamples. It follows from this last assertion that there is no non-empty set $B\varsubsetneq A$ such that $f(B)\subset B$. Indeed, if there was such a set it would follow from the bijectivity of $f$ that $f(A\setminus B)\subset A\setminus B$ and therefore, since $\#B,\#(A\setminus B)<\#A$, it would follow from our minimality assumption of $A$ that there are natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that ${f|_B}^m=\operatorname{Id}_B$ and that ${f|_{A\setminus B}}^m=\operatorname{Id}_{A\setminus B}$ and so $f^{mn}=\operatorname{Id}_A$. So, if we fix an element $a\in A$ and then we consider the sequence $a,f(a),f(f(a)),\ldots$ this sequence cannot have repeated elements until we have made $\#A$ iterations; otherwise, there would be a $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n<\#A-1$ such that$$f\bigl(\{a,f(a)\ldots,f^n(a)\}\bigr)\subset\{a,f(a)\ldots,f^n(a)\},$$contradicting what was just proved. Therefore$$A=\left\{a,f(a),\ldots,f^{\#A-1}(a)\right\},$$and it follows from this that $f^{\#A}=\operatorname{Id}_A$.

Answer (score 1):

Without (openly) invoking group theory:

There are only finitely many maps $A\to A$, hence we find natural numbers $n\ne m$ with $f^n=f^m$. Recall that injectivity allows us to conclude 
$$f\circ g=f\circ h\implies g=h.$$ Using this $\min\{n,m\}$ times on $f^n=f^m$, we arrive at $f^{|n-m|}=\operatorname{id}_A$.